# Why buffer overrun warning (C4789) only happens with compiler flag /O2?

Tags: c++, c

Consider the following code:

```
#include <memory.h>  

int p2[1];
int main()
{
    memset(&p2[1], 1, sizeof(int)); // C4789
}
```

If I compile this code with this command line:

*cl source.cpp*

This is the output:

> Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.11.25547 for x86
>   Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
>
> source.cpp
>   Microsoft (R) Incremental Linker Version 14.11.25547.0
>   Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
>
> /out:source.exe
>   source.obj

But iIf I compile this code with this another command line:

*cl /O2 source.cpp*

This is the output:

> Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.11.25547 for x86
>   Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
>
> source.cpp
>   d:\radar\src\radar\project1\source.cpp(6) : warning C4789: buffer 'p2' of size 4 bytes will be overrun; 4 bytes will be written starting at offset 4
>   Microsoft (R) Incremental Linker Version 14.11.25547.0
>   Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
>
> /out:source.exe
>   source.obj

Why this happened? Did I miss some compiler flag to activate warnings?
Would not be nice to have these warnings also in debug?

Comment: `p2[1]` is accessing the allocated memory out of bounds and the compiler can detect that, hence the warning. Indexing starts with `0`.

Comment: That is the purpose of the code, cause a warning, but it only happens with /O2 flag.

Comment: Ok, but I thought it could be a misunderstanding of mine about how optimization flags works. Stackoverflow.com is not for solving questions like that?

Comment: Well, how you present it it sounds like a bug. How may we become helpful to fix that beyond than telling you _"Your code exposes undefined behavior, just fix it"_. If the compiler doesn't detect that with a specific setting of flags (showing all of them in your question might be helpful for diagnosis) detects a bug or not?

Comment: The optimizer will try to replace memset() with simple MOVs.  Which works in this case, now it also knows that it doesn't fit.

Comment: Note that the C++ standard doesn't specify a standard header with the name `memory.h`.

Comment: @user0042 I'm not using anything else besides that.

Comment: @tambre This behaviour happens with /TC flag and with /TP flag too.

Comment: @tambre:  I think you're being overly critical here.  While it's true that memory.h isn't a standard header, the question isn't really about standards, it's about the Microsoft compiler, which does provide that header to both C and C++ programs.  Also, since the issue is in the "middle-end" of the compiler, whether the front-end is C or C++ or Pascal is kind of irrelevant.  The sample code can be compiled by this compiler in either C or C++ mode.  Furthermore, the question is likely useful to both C and C++ readers, so both tags are utterly appropriate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you enable certain types of optimizations, the compiler has to do more analysis of the data and control flow.  Sometimes that extra analysis can reveal bugs that would have been overlooked.

In particular, one difference between `/O2` and the default is that `/O2` enables intrinsic functions.

Without that optimization, the compiler just sees a call to some function.  Since it doesn't know what that "external library" function will do, there's not much more to be done.

But when you enable intrinsic functions, the compiler knows that `memset` is a special function that can be replaced with an intrinsic.  The `memset` is effectively inlined.  Now the compiler sees what `memset` is going to do with the parameters, and it can detect the overrun.